# Calling method from button click does not have compatible signature

Tags: wpf, vb.net, button

I'm getting a "...does not have a signature compatible with delegate..." message when trying to pass a parameter to a method.  Can someone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Step6Click("btnSubmit")

End Sub


Private Sub Step6Click(whereFrom As String)
```

Initially, no error is flagged but when the application is built, that's when the error occurs.

I changed ("btnSubmit") to ("xxx") thinking there was some conflict with passing "btnSubmit" when there was a button named the same.  Still get the error.

If I take out the parameter all together, then no error occurs, but I need to know in Step6Click where the call came from.

I can bypass the error by creating a property or variable called "whereFrom".  However I'd like to understand why this is an error.

Complete error message:

> Error 33  Method 'Private Sub Step6Click(whereFrom As String)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 
>   'Delegate Sub RoutedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)'.

Thanks.

Comment: That call to `Step6Click` is fine. A string is a string is a string. What else are you doing with `Step6Click`? Are you trying to use it as an event handler somewhere? Try Ctl+Shift+F and search your entire solution for "Step6Click".

Comment: You, somehow, made Step6Click() an event handler.  Look in you XAML.

Comment: Bizarrely, a WPF VB.NET project will allow you to use a method with no parameters as a routed event handler in XAML: `Click="Step6Click"`. However if it has any parameters *but not* the correct parameters for a `RoutedEventHandler` delegate, you'll get the error message you're seeing. C# WPF won't let you do that and you get *"No overload for 'Foo' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'."* if you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Step6Click` is an *event handler* that you are trying to hook up to the Click event of a Button in your XAML markup it should have the following signature or no parameters at all:

```
Private Sub Step6Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

You could create another method that you call from both your event handlers, i.e. just create another method with a different name, e.g.:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Step6ClickMethod("btnSubmit")
End Sub

Private Sub Step6Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Step6ClickMethod("btnSubmit")
End Sub

Private Sub Step6ClickMethod(ByVal whereFrom As String)

End Sub
```

Comment: Step6Click is referenced three places.  The two shown in my original post and here in the xaml:  <Button Width="45" Click="Step6Click" Height="35" >.    Is the xaml causing the error?

Comment: After rereading Ed Plunkett's reply, this seems to be the situation I'm in.  So it sounds like I need to create a public property or variable called "whereFrom" and use that rather than passing the value.

Comment: Why can't you just create a method as I suggested ?

Comment: @EManning No, no, don't pass the parameter in a field, that's seriously, seriously crazy. It's very easy to solve the problem using normal means. Never do something strange and crazy just to avoid doing something easy and sensible. Just create a new event handler method for that one click handler, and call `Step6Click("Whatever")` from that event handler. Easy.

Comment: OK, I will follow mm8's suggestion.  Thanks to you all.